# Change Bean Reference dynamically in Spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I am working on Spring based web application and initialing by bean using XML. I am trying to change reference of a bean dynamically. 
I have a Facade class

```
 PortalFacade -> DataBaseService where it interact with DB.
```

Now I have a situation where I want to start using FileBaseService without application restart. I am maintaining a Property with value ( DBSWITCH=ON/OFF) which is a ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource of spring.

So now as soon as it finds switch as OFF, I have to change the reference to

```
 PortalFacade -> FileBaseService.
```

So now onwards any new request  coming to my portal should me serviced by FileBaseService.

what I tried is following with a Thread which will perfrom this look up and work for me to assign new bean reference but failed to achieve

```
    SpringObjectFactory fact=BaseSpringObjectFactory.getInstance();
```

// Is my customer Classes in Application to hold reference to application context.

```
    aisConfig.isAisEnabled()) // Identifies SWITCH ON & OFF

   while(true)
{
    System.out.println("Thread Running ...................");

    SpringObjectFactory fact=BaseSpringObjectFactory.getInstance();
    if(fact != null && fact.getApplicationContext()!=null)
    {
        AISConfigManager aisConfig = (AISConfigManager) fact.getBean("aisConfig");
        if(aisConfig !=null && aisConfig.isAisEnabled())
        {
            System.out.println("Changing Bean Reference ...............");
            PortalFacade portalFacade = (PortalFacade ) fact.getBean("portalFacade ");
            IBaseService filebaseService = new FileBaseService();

            portalFacade.setBaseService(filebaseService );


        }
        else
        {
            PortalFacade portalFacade = (PortalFacade ) fact.getBean("portalFacade ");
            IBaseService dbService= new DataBaseService();

            portalFacade.setBaseService(dbService);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Going to sleep...................................");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

// When I debug it is assigns new bean reference but when I access Portal it doesn't pick by the new bean reference but takes the bean reference specified in xml.
Is there any other way I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use another layer of abstraction. Create a

```
@Service
class DelegatingBaseService implements IBaseService {
    @Autowired
    private FileBaseService fileBaseService;
    @Autowired
    private DataBaseService dataBaseService;

    @Override
    public void baseServiceMethod1() {
        getDelegate().baseServiceMethod1();
    }

    @Override
    public Object baseServiceMethod2(Object input) {
        return getDelegate().baseServiceMethod2(input);
    }

    private IBaseService getDelegate() {
        if (aisConfig != null && aisConfig.isAisEnabled()) {
            return fileBasedService;
        } else {
            return dataBaseService;
        }
    }
}
```

Then use the `DelegatingBaseService` in the clients.

Comment: the above solution is quite impressing but wonder if we have something that can be achieved in spring.. may be destroy and recreate this beans again.. Not sure how to do it.